# Simple REGEX to find ON TAPE Numbers

Tags: regex

I need to find the string **‘ON TAPE (000012, 000013)’**.  The number of course changes each time I need to search.  I've been trying to learn regex, but I'm not taking to it very well.  Anyone mind filling in the blank for me with a regex that will locate the string **‘ON TAPE (000012, 000013)’**  ?

Comment: what is the language ? (php, javascript, python)

Comment: `/\w+\s+\w+\([^()]+\)/`

Comment: All by itself, you can match it with `.+`. Anything more specific will narrow it down. `ON TAPE.*`, more specific `ON TAPE\(.*` and on and on until `ON TAPE \(\d+, \d+\)` You can even generalize specifically `ON\s+TAPE\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D` So it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome :)

```
(.*?\(\d+\, \d+\))
```

Check this out: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rM4sA4/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is all dependent on the exact flavor of regex that you are using. Different languages handle regular expressions differently. Assuming that *only* the number is going to change, you could try

#### POSIX

With a POSIX-compliant regex engine, the `()` characters represent grouping, so they need to be escaped.

```
/ON\sTAPE\s\(\d+,\s\d+\)/
```

- `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `\(` and `\)` match the parentheses
- `\d` matches any numeric character
- `+` means that the previous character can be repeated 1 to n times

#### javascript

For this particular case, javascript is POSIX-compliant.

#### php

For this particular case, php is POSIX-compliant.

#### python

For this particular case, python is POSIX-compliant.

#### grep

With grep, you don't need to escape the brackets, it doesn't handle the `+` character or the `\d` character.

```
ON\sTAPE\s([0-9][0-9]*,\s[0-9][0-9]*)
```

- `\s` matches any whitespace character
- `[0-9]` matches any numeric character
- `*` means that the previous character can be repeated 0 to `n` times.

PS. The link that Nikolas shared is really useful :)